# Adding a red * next to the input form field in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms, validation

I'm wanting to add a red `*` at the end of my input field within bootstrap but everything that I have tried so far has not helped much at all. Does the bootstrap column max the

Here is what's happening at the moment:

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
.required-after::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
  <label for="ACI_client-name-input" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label">Client Name</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8 required-after"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="ACI_client-name-input" placeholder="Ex" required></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `::before`?

Comment: Just goes on top of the input box, not to the right.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap 3, that's what the employer is stuck with.

Comment: I ran the snippet and it loads it to the right? Do you mean to the right of the label, or actually inside the input field?

Comment: Why not put it after the label? Do you want it after the input?

Comment: @Jake, truthfully I am shocked, in the run snippet it goes to the right spot but in my code it does not.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents Dude, Bootstrap 3 is good. Don't worry! `:)`

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents It doesn't allow in Bootstrap. Yes! `:(` https://www.bootply.com/4ZbtQwWlvD Tried: https://www.bootply.com/9HfG0oMosw

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents Made it work... Enjoy! `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```css
.required-after::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
.required-after input {
  float: left;
  width: 98%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <label for="ACI_client-name-input" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label">Client Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8 required-after"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="ACI_client-name-input" placeholder="Ex" required=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Bootply: https://www.bootply.com/HS9m4wWBzW**

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks @praveen!

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents This doesn't use FlexBox, so this method is also supported in old browsers like IE 7+! `:)`

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents Is there anything else I could help you with?

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents Have a nice day bud! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Use flex like shown below.

```css
.required-after {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.required-after span {
  color: red;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <label for="ACI_client-name-input" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label">Client Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8 required-after"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="ACI_client-name-input" placeholder="Ex" required> <span class="">* </span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS snippet would surely help you.

```
.required-after::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```